# What is correct syntax to use the php date function in a query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, syntax

So I have a problem, how do you use the php date function in a query in a php script. I want to convert the sql date from my database in the format Ymd. I don't want to change the format in my database but in my script. But I don't know how to do this. I think the problem lies in my syntax. Any help is appreciated.

My script:

```
 <?php
    require_once('config.php');  
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');

    session_start();

    $conn = @mysqli_connect(MYSQL_SERVER, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASS, MYSQL_DB);
    if (!$conn) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    }


    $res = $conn -> query("select sum(food.calories) as total_calories, date("Ymd",strtotime(log.dates)) as datum 
                           from foods food inner join foodlog log 
                           on food.id = log.fooditem 
                           where log.user = {$_SESSION['userid']}
                           group by datum 
                           order by datum");

    if ( !$res ) {
        die('Wrong query: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $data = array();

    for ($x = 0; $x < mysqli_num_rows($res); $x++) {
        $data[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
    }

    echo json_encode($data);     

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL has its own date functions. Use *them*. In this case use [`DATE_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

```
$res = $conn -> query("select sum(food.calories) as total_calories, DATE_FORMAT(log.dates, '%y%m%d') as datum 
                       from foods food inner join foodlog log 
                       on food.id = log.fooditem 
                       where log.user = {$_SESSION['userid']}
                       group by datum 
                       order by datum");
```